# NoSqlBooster is not Runing on Ubuntu | NoSqlBooster Appimage not working in Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, nosql

Doubling clicking the appimage did not work following commands

```
 chmod a+x nosqlbooster4mongo*.AppImage
 ./nosqlbooster4mongo*.AppImage
```

gives me the error

```
dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2

AppImages require FUSE to run. 
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

Run commands:

```
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use FUSE then you can follow the steps below:

Step-1: Run chmod a+x with file. Run the terminal in same directory with same file name or you can drag & drop the downloaded file.

```
chmod a+x nosqlbooster4mongo*.AppImage
```

Step-2: Extract the appImage file

```
./nosqlbooster4mongo*.AppImage --appimage-extract
```

Step-3: Go to the folder which is created by extraction, find the file and then double click or you can run in terminal with file name:

```
./nosqlbooster4mongodb
```

Note: '*' sign is actually version number. After using chmod a+x fileName.AppImage a directory will be created for the app at home/.config/